# How to get a correct result of binary string intersection in Entity to Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I save my data in a binary-look string, "100010" ,for example. And I want to check whether it has same value in corresponding place with the other string "100000".
So I try to use "Intersection". In this Condition, the result of intersection will be "100000", and it could be seen as the item I need for my requirement. But how can I use this conception when I query a Entity to Linq statement?

Here is my thought:

```
var chemicals = db.ChemicalItem.Where(c => c.CategoryNumber.ToCharArray().Intersect(catekey.ToCharArray()).Count()>0);
```

"CategoryNumber" is my data, and "catekey" is the string for comparing. Both of them are binary-look string(cantain 6 chars). And if the count is not 0,they have '1's in the same index. And I can get the correct query.

Sadly, It didn't work. I always get DbExpressionBinding Error. Can somone tell me What's Wrong? Thanks.

PS:I'm not good at English and post the question here first time, sorry for my bad expression and thank for your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is trying to create a SQL query out of your condition, but is not able to do it for the expression you specified.

One way to "fix" the problem would be to do the filtering in code instead of in SQL, but this will impact performance, because all of the records will be retrieved to the client and filtered there. This is how you could do it (notice the added `ToList()`):

```
var chemicals = db.ChemicalItem.ToList().Where(c => c.CategoryNumber.ToCharArray().Intersect(catekey.ToCharArray()).Count()>0);
```

A suggested way would be to do the filtering in SQL, but in this case you will need to write an equivalent stored procedure in SQL which will do the filtering and call that from your EF code. Still such filtering will not be very effective because SQL will not be able to use any indices and will always need to do a table scan.

Comment: OK, I'll try this way. Thanks a lot :)